# How do I make the Android editor read-only and support carriage returns?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

How do I make the Android editor read-only and support carriage returns?

I have discovered that setting the input type to 0 results in carriage returns being ignored.

**NOTE:**

I am using Xamarin.Forms

Answer (score 0):

You would need a custom renderer, then on Android EditText use (code written from memory):

```
editText.SetKeyListener(null);
// Prevent paste from clipboard
editText.Focusable = false;
editText.FocusableInTouchMode = false;
editText.LongClickable = false;
```

Standard `EditorView` allows carriage returns, so we won't change that. By using this custom renderer you're simply hiding keyboard for your `EditorView` (`SetKeyListener(null)`), then to prevent user from doing clipboard paste (all other lines of code).

Comment: Also, I do not see how this logic preserves carriage returns. Which line handles this?

Comment: I updated the answer. Why do you need it to be focusable?

Comment: The user needs to select a from a list of panes in order to invoke an operation. These panes contain multi line text.